# ion-navbar in ion-header lags when swiping (ios) - Ionic

Tags: html, ios, css, angular, ionic-framework

Here is a video of the problem:

[image]

The part that is sticking (the TRESemme ad) has this for `html`:

```
<ion-header #ionheader (swipeLeft)="toProfile()" (swipeRight)="toBooking()">
  <ion-navbar #clickme class="itemadspace" [@slideDown]="downState" no-padding>
    <ion-item class="ad" no-padding no-lines>
      <div (tap)="loadPost()" class='pluscontainer'>
        <ion-icon class='plussy' name="add"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-navbar>

...
```

Here is the relevant `css`:

```
    .ad {
        background-image: url('../../assets/tresemme.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .itemadspace {
        z-index: 1;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

I am putting an `ion-item` inside the `ion-navbar` because it is the only way I could get the background image to show up (it was just a blank white background). I also came across nesting it this way because I couldn't get the yellow plus sign to show up. How do I make the TRESemme ad section swipe at the same time as the rest of the content? The toolbar with `All / Classes / Products` animates correctly and it is also inside the `ion-header`. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but Sass variables can be used to target stuff. Try typing 'item' in search here https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/ and then use that in conjunction with Chrome Developer Tools to target elements and styles.. See what classes are being assigned for ion-item etc and see if you can tweak scss.

Comment: yah the setup seems a little hacky with the `item` inside the `navbar` - this is the only way I could get a background image to show up...but im gonna try your section which i think would be targeting the classes of the `navbar` without having to use the item at all. When I was trying it that way...the background image wouldn't show up...but now I'll try to add the background image to one of the other classes created by `ion-navbar`

Comment: it seems like its the `item` is what sticks...not its container (the `navbar`)

Comment: Sometimes if you are having problems with this stuff it is also useful to go look at the component source code on Github and see if that gives further enlightenment too. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/item/item.ts - have a snoop around the component folder at various components.